# Editing localStorage with a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm working on a simple Chrome extension, that integrates with a certain web app. That app is built with React, and uses `localStorage` to store the state of the app, which is useful to me.

Reading the data is not an issue, but writing it seems to be impossible using Javascript. Here's where I save the change:

```js
replaceText(code, replacement) {
    const { text } = this.getActiveThread();
    const replacedText = text.replace(code, replacement);
    const lsItem = getSingleItem(this.activeThreadId);
    lsItem.someValue = replacedText;
    saveToStorage(this.activeThreadId, lsItem);
}
```

`getSingleItem` returns the parsed item from `localStorage`, and `saveToStorage` does the inverse of that.

I have the Application tab open in Dev tools, and I can see the change is saved when I call `replaceText`, but it's reverted after a second or so. If I apply the change in dev tools manually, the change is saved.

Is this a Chrome feature, or does the app I'm trying to modify change the value back? If so, how would I go about figuring out how to properly change the value?

Comment: Then how come when I change the value manually, the change persists and is seen in the app?

Comment: Or maybe that webapp detects devtools being open and polls localStorage. Or maybe it listens to [storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/storage) event, in which case you can dispatch it manually.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions - I'll give them a try and let you know.

Comment: Yep, that's the case. I already checked if there's a listener, but I'm afraid this won't work. I haven't tested it yet, but I tried dispatching events on the app before, but it only seems to register the ones where `isTrusted === true` :/

Comment: In that case you can try opening the site in an iframe inside your background page or as an inactive new tab (with pinned:true option to make it less distracting), set localStorage, and remove the iframe or close the tab - the key here is to run the code in a separate process.

Comment: Another hack is to use `chrome.debugger` API and invoke [setDOMStorageItem](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/DOMStorage/#method-setDOMStorageItem).